# Commenting code in Scheme

Tags: scheme, comments

I am looking at some code in `Scheme` from `Festival` and cannot seem to figure out the comments. Currently, I can see `;`, `;;` and `;;;` used to indicate comment lines. Other sources on the web indicate that some of the above maybe ways to indicate multi-line comments. My questions are:

1. What is the difference between `;`, `;;` and `;;;` for commenting?
2. When is one to be used over the other?
3. Is there any other, IMO saner, way to comment code in `Scheme`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The comment character is ; and anything following that on the line will be ignored.  The difference is visual.  I have often seen a single ; used if the comment is on a line with code, ;; if the comment is on a line by itself, and ;;; if it's a heading of some sort.  The most important thing in commenting is likely to follow whatever conventions you see in the code you're working with.

Comment: Goes along well with the [Racket style guide](https://docs.racket-lang.org/style/Choosing_the_Right_Construct.html?q=comments#%28part._.Comments%29)

Comment: It's kinda like using `//` vs `///` in many other languages...

Answer (score 52):

All three of the forms you mention are single-line comments. The double-semicolon may have originally arisen as a cue in Dorai Sitaram's SLaTeX typesetting package that the comment was to be typeset as ordinary text, rather than as program text.

Scheme also has multi-line comments.

In particular, it appears that R6RS, like Racket, allows the use of `#|` and `|#` to begin and end multi-line comments. Also, the utterly magnificent `#;` combination comments out a full s-expression. So, for instance, if you write

```
#;(define (terrible-function a)
    (totally-broken-code
     here))
```

The entire definition is considered commented-out.

Comment: `;#` or just `;` both identical to `#;`, in their effect.

Comment: No, `;#` and `;` are not identical to `#;`... Try running my example code, and then change the `#;` into a `;#` and run again.

Comment: EDIT: perhaps it's not clear that I'm speaking of Racket and R6RS scheme here, and not older or different versions of scheme. Racket and R6RS both support the `#;` form.

Comment: You right, I'm wrong =). `#;`, indeed comments out the whole definition, while `;#` and `;` comment out only single line. P.S.: it was perfectly clear that you were talking about Racket and R6RS scheme, it's just that I have tested it shallowly.

Comment: Well, that's very civil of you. If I upvote your comment, is that appreciative, or just mean? :)

Comment: Very nice to see a reasonably cordial disagreement.  I've upvoted all :)

Answer (score 3):

MIT/GNU Scheme allows the use of `;` for single-line comments and `#|` and `|#` respectively for opening and closing multiline comments. Just tested on version 10.1.10.