# Can Lisp's macro system also extend its commenting syntax?

Tags: macros, lisp, comments, racket

[I love Racket's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8265273/10319707) `#;`. I want to see it in every language that I ever use again. Can it be added to other Lisps via their macro systems? Or does the commenting character break the macro system's ability to read the code?

A sufficient answer will demonstrate a macro being built in any Lisp other than Racket that allows for a change in the commenting system. You need not actually implement Racket's `#;`, but I would like it if you do. Lisps with the least similarity to Racket, e.g. Clojure or any non-Scheme will be particularity nice to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#;` isn't a macro, it's what Common lisp would call a *readmacro*: what it does is defined at read time, not later than that.  Read macros which aim to completely suppress input are mildly perilous because there needs to be a way of saying 'read the following thing, but ignore it', and that's only possible if any *other* readmacros behave well: there's nothing to stop someone defining a readmacro which produces some side-effect even if reading is suppressed.

However, well-behaved readmacros (which includes all of the standard ones and the rest of the standard reader) in CL won't do that: they'll listen to whether reading is being suppressed, and behave accordingly.

CL allows you to do this as standard by using its conditionalisation on features, and in particular `#+(or) <expr>` will always skip `<expr>`.

But you can define your own: `#;` is not predefined so you can define it:

```
(set-dispatch-macro-character
 #\# #\;
 (lambda (stream char n)
   (declare (ignore char))
   (let ((*read-suppress* t))
     (dotimes (i (or n 1) (values))
       (read stream)))))
```

After this, or at least with a better tested version of this, then `#; <expr>` (or obviously `#;<expr>`) will read as whitespace, and `#2; ... ...` will skip two following expressions:

```
> (let ((x #;1 #2; 2 3 4)) x)
4
```

Comment: You might get a better example by copy and pasting the Racket example from the answer linked in the question. Anyway, well done!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`#+(or)`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dhq.htm) reader macro.

Since `(or)` evaluates to `nil`, the condition is always false the following form is never evaluated.